# How can we change the color and font of half string in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a string "* HostName"
I'm putting this in `propertygrid`.

Do we have any way to change the color and font of `*` before putting into a `propertygrid`?

Comment: Well, it does have an `OnPaint(PaintEventArgs)` event..

Comment: Custom painting - yea